# JSON stripping leading 0 from numeric string

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

So, I have some jQuery-based javascript that makes an Ajax call to a PHP function.

```
updatemarkers.xhr = $.post( ih.url("/AjaxSearch/map_markers/"), params).done( function(json) {
    <stuff>
}
```

The php function returns this array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => IL-MLSNI
    [1] => 06339655
    [2] => 41.93027100
    [3] => -87.98229900
    [4] => 0
)
```

But the JSON array treats array[1] as "6339655", which is wrong.  Is there a straightforward way to handle this? Note array[0], indicating which MLS the data comes from, and the second parameter is always a string, no matter whether numeric or not, so the leading 0 in this case is pertinent.

My backup plan is to prepend some obnoxious character to the string in PHP that I will strip off in javascript, but for 2% of the entries in our DB, that seems a little awkward.

Comment: if you want a string, use a string

Comment: A leading zero on a number does not have any semantic meaning. With or without any quantity of leading zeros, it's the same value.

Comment: This is a php question, not a javascript question. Your php code is sending a number in json. Please post more php code around how the json is encoded from an array. You may need to format the number to string in php.

Comment: Here is an example php to encode an array to a string. Note the output number is a string with quotes. https://repl.it/GQhO/0 and here is a js example which accurately decodes the string into an object http://jsbin.com/bevasevise/edit?js,console

Comment: The fact is that it is NOT a number, it's a numeric string. Therefore, a leading 0 DOES have semantic value. especially when I am using it to search in a third party database.  I am looking into my PHP code, though there is no place where we explicitly convert the string I extract from my database ( mysql varchar(20) column) into an integer. Sometimes I really miss languages with explicit types.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found the problem. Someone "optimized" the JSON by using the JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK option on json_encode. Had to dig down a couple of levels into our Controller code. Sheesh.